# Synapse Analytics Data tab not showing data pool

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I am learning Azure, and I've created a Synapse Analytics workspace. Inside it, I've created a new dedicated sql pool:

[image]

But fore some reason, unknown to me, that sql pool is not shown (it's missing) in the Data tab, under Workspace:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try reloading and see if you can find

Comment: clear the cache and reload the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You need to refresh the browser after `dedicated sql pool` deployment completes. Try refreshing the browser, you should see your dedication SQL database under `data` menu.